# Are some C++ standard library constexpr functions implicitly allowed to be consteval since C++20?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, language-implementation

Since C++20, there are immediate functions, whose addresses can't be taken in many cases ([P1073R3](https://wg21.link/p1073r3)); and most standard library functions are made non-addressable ([P0551R3](https://wg21.link/p0551r3)).

Also, there are some `constexpr` standard function always returning the same constant value (e.g. static member functions of [standard `std::numeric_limits` specializations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits), [`std::barrier<F>::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/barrier/max)), and none of them is addressable.

Can implementations conformingly change these functions to `consteval`?

I intended to make such a change in standard library implementations and opened a [discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/discussions/3604) in MSVC STL's repo, without receiving any answer so far. And I also wonder whether such change is an improvement, since it possibly reduces the size of symbol tables.

Comment: [\[constexpr.functions\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/constexpr.functions) talks specifically about `constexpr` instead of "_constexpr functions_", so it would presumably permit adding `consteval` even on functions that are not `constexpr` according to specification, but that does not seem to be in the spirit of that clause.

Comment: A better argument would be to make these functions instances of `std::integral_constant` instances. Thus, they can be used with or without braces(implicit integral conversion kicks in). The type also would reflect `constexpr`ness of the result and can be used as a `concept` in template programming. This also can replace none-type template parameters and simplify `template template` programming.

Answer (score 4):

> Can implementations conformingly change these functions to `consteval`?

It depends on the individual function.
If there are any parameters, then the answer is no:

```cpp
consteval int f(int i) { return i; }

constexpr int g(int i) {
    // error: call to consteval function 'f(i)' is not a constant expression
    return f(i) + 1;
}
```

This happens because a `consteval` function must only be called with compile-time arguments (this is an over-simplification, it's a bit more complicated) and a `constexpr` function can have parameters which exist only at runtime.
See also [P1938R3: §3.1 Interaction between constexpr and consteval](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1938r3.html#interaction-between-constexpr-and-consteval)

That being said, `consteval` functions with *no parameters* which are not explicitly addressable can be made `consteval`, since there is no observable difference between a `constexpr` and `consteval` function invocation with no arguments. It would be a classic case of the "as-if rule".
See also: [What exactly is the "as-if" rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15718262/5740428)

**However, it would be an ABI-break to do this retroactively.** If there are existing applications that make a call to say, `std::numeric_limits<float>::max()`, this call would produce a linker error because `consteval` functions don't get emitted into the library.
Therefore, implementers may be hesitant to modify existing functions like that.
Of course, this refers to debug builds, where `::max()` hasn't been inlined.
See also: [P2028: What is ABI, and What Should WG21
Do About It?](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2028r0.pdf)

Comment: I guess this won't be ABI-breaking. As such `max` is an inline function (by the nature of `constexpr`), the caller TU should already contain a non-inlined body if needed.